# SQL Query to Delete only those rows where Sum of Adjacent Row value in a column is zero and Date column has difference of 90 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input  -

```
Posting Date    Amount in doc. curr.
2/28/2015        -679,407.79
3/17/2015         679,407.79
7/31/2014        -644,521.00
8/18/2015         644,521.00
8/30/2015        -153,144.88
```

Output -

```
Posting Date Amount in doc. curr.
7/31/2014      -644,521.00
8/18/2015       644,521.00
8/30/2015      -153,144.88
```

in this example  , though -644,521.00 and 644,521.00 sum is zero but Difference in posting Date (8/18/2015,7/31/2014) is more than 90 days, so these rows should not be deleted. -153,144.88 is indvidual amount with no +ve match, so this row also will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
INTO   #test
FROM   (VALUES (Cast('2/28/2015' AS DATE),-679407.79),
               (Cast('3/17/2015' AS DATE),679407.79),
               (Cast('7/31/2014' AS DATE),-644521.00),
               (Cast('8/18/2015' AS DATE),644521.00),
               (Cast('8/30/2015' AS DATE),-153144.88) ) cs (p_date, amount);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Max(p_date)OVER(partition BY Abs(amount)) mx_date,
                Min(p_date)OVER(partition BY Abs(amount)) mn_date,
                Sum(amount)OVER(partition BY Abs(amount)) AS s_amt,
                *
         FROM   #test)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  Datediff(dd, mn_date, mx_date) < 90
       AND s_amt = 0
```

Comment: just found that "over partition by" does not in work in MS ACCESS SQLor EXCEL VBA SQL. any other alternative?

Comment: @baimzz -Yes thats correct but the answer is because you have tagged Sql Server which does support `over partition by`

Comment: do you have any alternate way of it ? so that it can be used in ms access as well?